# Transistor based Colpitts Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

I am building a Colpitts Oscillator that produces a frequency of 500 kHz with 5 volts peak to peak. I think I have designed the tank circuit correctly but I am not sure how to bias the transistor properly so that I get sustained oscillations and so that the oscillations remain at 5 volts peak to peak.Here is my work so far:[image]
[image]

Comment: Your design is reasonable, and should oscillate. Perhaps your simulator needs a smaller time-step. Or your oscillator needs a kick-start.

Answer (score 0):

The PI resonator has 8:1 stepup ratio; thus 5 volts input will become (ignoring Rin of the gain stage as the load) 40 volts. I'd rethink that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. what do you mean by the PI resonator has a 8:1 ratio?